# How can I compare the content of files in 2 different directories

Tags: macos, comparison

Can you please tell me how can I compare the content content of each files under 2 different directories hierarchy? I am on MacOS X platform?

Thank you.

Comment: Try Meld for visual comparison. I use it to compare directories, it can compare 3 folders, files etc. URL: http://meldmerge.org/

Comment: Kumar, Meld is awesome on Linux. You should add this as an answer - although it requires Fink/Brew/macports to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/index.html) may do what you need:

> Performs a side-by-side comparison of 2 folders, showing which files are only present in one file or the other, as well as file pairs which are identical or different.
>
> Graphically shows the changes between two files. Includes intra-line highlighting and full support for editing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the developer tools installed, you will have filemerge, which can compare 2 directories. However - if you haven't it would be a rather big thing to install just for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to see the changes for each file in a visual diff program like [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) you can do:

```
diff -rq tantan-s3 tantan-s3-cloudfront | awk '{ print $2 " " $4 }'| xargs -L 1 ksdiff
```

The diff command with the -q option gets a listing of files that differ in the following format:

```
Files tantan-s3/readme.txt and tantan-s3-cloudfront/readme.txt differ
Files tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/admin-options.html and tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/admin-options.html differ
Files tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/class-plugin-public.php and tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/class-plugin-public.php differ
Files tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/class-plugin.php and tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/class-plugin.php differ
Files tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/config-sample.php and tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/config-sample.php differ
Files tantan-s3/wordpress-s3.php and tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3.php differ
```

The awk command cleans this up to just have the file names:

```
tantan-s3/readme.txt tantan-s3-cloudfront/readme.txt
tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/admin-options.html tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/admin-options.html
tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/class-plugin-public.php tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/class-plugin-public.php
tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/class-plugin.php tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/class-plugin.php
tantan-s3/wordpress-s3/config-sample.php tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3/config-sample.php
tantan-s3/wordpress-s3.php tantan-s3-cloudfront/wordpress-s3.php
```

The the xargs command with the -L 1 option executes Kaleidascope for each set of file pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Beyond compare" to do it, and [it seems](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=450236) that the MAC equivalent is [bbedit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)

Comment: Absolutely not. BBEdit is a general purpose and developers' text editor that perhaps has some diff functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the command line, you can use the UNIX 'diff' command.

An example of a command to run a compare using diff could be:

**diff -r /my/first/directory /my/second/directory**

This will recursively perform a diff on all common directories and files between the two directories.

Reference:
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 4 beta now runs also on OSX.
It's a good comparison tool with a GUI that could do compare, sync, merge for files and folders.

http://www.scootersoftware.com/beta.php?zz=beta4_dl